# Using alloc with optimizations enabled causes crash with illegal instruction

Tags: rust

The following rust code:

```rust
use std::alloc;

fn main() {
    let name = String::from("a");
    let obj = unsafe { GcObject::allocate(name) };

    println!("{:?}", obj.object);
}

pub struct GcObject {
    object: *mut Object,
}

impl GcObject {
    pub unsafe fn allocate(object: String) -> Self {
        let layout = alloc::Layout::new::<Object>();

        // Allocate the object
        let ptr = alloc::alloc(layout) as *mut Object;

        if ptr.is_null() {
            eprintln!("Alloc error!");
            alloc::handle_alloc_error(layout);
        }

        *ptr = Object { kind: object };

        GcObject { object: ptr }
    }
}

struct Object {
    kind: String,
}
```

Rustc version: `rustc 1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)`
Platform: `Fedora Linux 38`

When compiled with following runs fine:
`rustc main.rs -C opt_level=0`

But when compiled with optimizations enabled like:
`rustc main.rs -C opt_level=3`
Causes a crash when run with the following message:

`Illegal instruction(core dumped)`

So, is there any way to fix this or there is something wrong with my code.

Comment: I think your code triggers UB because, when you do `*ptr = ...`, the content of `ptr` can be uninitialized memory, yet nobody told Rust, therefore it will try to drop it. I think you should use `ptr::write` instead or something like that. Or, most likely, you should probably allocate using `Box`, then leak the box to handle the allocation yourself, which is entirely safe.

Comment: Writing unsafe code is _hard_.

Comment: @jthulhu yeah, that works out. Did not know that assigning a value to a pointer causes a drop, since I've never written unsafe code before. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code triggers undefined behavior when assigning the value behind `ptr`. Indeed, unless a value is marked as maybe uninitialized, Rust assumes that every value is initialized, and therefore writing a new value in place of an old one requires `drop`ing the old value (which in your case does *something* because your data contains a `String`, which has some cleanup code).

Instead, you could use `MaybeUninit` or `ptr::write` to avoid this implicit deallocation cleanup. But they're both unsafe. A better (safer) solution is to allocate using `Box::new`, and then leak the pointer with `Box::leak`.

FYI, all `unsafe` functions in the Rust standard library have the exact conditions that have to be satisfied not to trigger UB in their documentation. Since writing unsafe code is hard because there are a *lot* of things that might trigger UB that one cannot guess, it's wise to check every single unsafe operation and add a comment to explain why the operation was correctly used.

Comment: Yeah, it works now and is much better, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AVX-42 if you are writing a lot of unsafe code, you might want to try miri. It's a tool that adds some instrumentation to detect UB. It's not exhaustive, but I think it would have caught this error, which is better than a random error message that only appears with certain compilation options.

Comment: It does catch it indeed, just checked on the playground - it reports using (namely, dropping) uninitialized data and shows the exact line of the source code.